# C# Array List of ArrayList

Tags: c#, java, arraylist

I have an arraylist of string objects, that then gets added into and arraylist of arraylists.

As a java developer I used to use Vectors, I know now defunct but the name sounds great haha!!, I also used ArrayList which both had access to the sub arraylist by means of, for example

```
ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>();
array.add("test");

ArrayList<ArrayList> array2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList>()
array2.add(array1);

string var = array2.get(1).get(2);
```

What is this equivilent in C#?

Comment: Did you even do an attempt to search for the answer? List ...

Comment: You should start to choose answers on your questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the `List<T>` generic class:

```
List<string> array1 = new List<string>();
array1.Add("test");

List<List<string>> array2 = new List<List<string>>();
array2.Add(array1);

string myStr = array2[0][0]; //Whatever indexers you want here
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var array1 = new List<string>();
array1.Add("test");

var array2 = new List<List<string>>();
array2.Add(array1);

var originalString = array2[0][0]; // or array2[1][2] if there's an item there
```